# Problem estimating Qt Slot as Error in Cppcheck Analysis

Tags: c++, qt, static-analysis, cppcheck

While performing static analysis with Cppcheck, the corresponding error message was printed in the slots part, but I don't know how to solve this part. Can you help me?

err_msg : There is an unknown macro here somewhere. Configuration is required. If slots is a macro then please configure it.

```
#ifndef A_H
#define A_H

#include "BasePopup.hpp"

namespace Ui {
class A;
}

class A: public BasePopup
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    A();
    ~A();
    ...
protected:
    ...

private:
    ...

signals:
    ...

private slots: // err_msg
    ...
};

#endif // A_H
```

Compilation and build work well without any problems, but only considered errors in Cppcheck static analysis.

- For your information, I'm working on "visual studio code".

Comment: Qt is a C++ framework, please don't mix C and C++, they are very distinct programming languages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you run cppcheck command line tool, run it with the command line parameter

```
--library=qt
```

If you run cppcheck in [Qt Creator](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-cppcheck.html), no extra actions are needed.